# How can I stop a slick-slider from auto rotate?

Tags: autorotate

I wanna stop a slick-slider from auto rotating. I do not have the code but need to overwrite it.

```
<slick-slider>
 <slick-list>
  <slick-track>

   <slick-slide>
   </slick-slide>
   <slick-slide>
   </slick-slide>

  <slick-track>
 <slick-list>
<slick-slider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the autoplay: false

HTML

```
<div class="slider autoplay">
  <div><h3>1</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2</h3></div>
  <div><h3>3</h3></div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.autoplay').on('init', function(slick) {
$('.slick-dots').on('click',function() {
    $('.autoplay').slick('slickPause');
});
}).slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
  autoplay: false,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
})
```

make sure you have linked the slick and jquery.